# Is it possible to configure a light node in Ganache private ethereum network which does not take part in consensus or block validation phase?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ganache

If I want to send  a transaction from a light node which does not maintain full copy of blockchain ledger is it possible using Ganache?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the transaction to mainnet, there's no need to maintain a node, you just need to send transaction to a public rpc, like infura.

But if your requirement is to test things out in a private network, you can use ganache or build one by yourself.

[Here](https://github.com/huahuayu/ethereum-local-private-network) are some scripts to build ethereum/bsc/fantom/avalanche private network.

Comment: Please add some details from the link, it case it gets broken, or so people and web crawlers can get some info about the answer.